# How can Python code with Tkinter mainloop be tested?

Tags: python, testing, tkinter

How can I test the following code with nosetests?

```
# GUI
try:
    # for Python2
    import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    # for Python3
    import tkinter as tk


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=250, height=250)
    canvas.pack()
    root.bind('<B1-Motion>', lambda x: True)
    root.bind('<Button-1>', lambda x: True)
    root.mainloop()
```

When I call `main()` the mainloop gets executed. How can I prevent that?

Comment: The code you want to test would be better off in its own module or functions/classes seperate from the gui code. This way it can be tested independantly of the gui. The gui code would call the seperate code when it needs to.

Answer (score 0):

To stop the mainloop() running, you could comment out the line, this would run main() without Tkinter creating the canvas.

```
try:
    # for Python2
     import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
     # for Python3
    import tkinter as tk


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=250, height=250)
    canvas.pack()
    root.bind('<B1-Motion>', lambda x: True)
    root.bind('<Button-1>', lambda x: True)
    #root.mainloop() """#stops the line being run"""
main()
```

or have the root.mainloop() outside the main() function and comment out mainloop()

```
try:
    # for Python2
     import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
     # for Python3
    import tkinter as tk
def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=250, height=250)
    canvas.pack()
    root.bind('<B1-Motion>', lambda x: True)
    root.bind('<Button-1>', lambda x: True)
main()
#root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The first one is OK. The second got NameError: name 'root' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling root.mainloop() the idea is to call root.update(). This will run the tk loop only once (any pending event will hence be dispatched and handled by your application).

Testing the application behavior becomes then a succession of steps like:

```
root.event_generate('<B1-Motion>') # will generate a "fake" event <B1-Motion>
root.update()
# test that '<B1-Motion>' callback was correctly executed (by eg checking an expected state of you app
root.event_generate('<Button-1>')
root.update()
# test ....
```

Note that you can also directly invoke button (as if they were clicked) by calling 
button.invoke()

Answer (score 0):

You can redesign this into a Class:

```py
import tkinter as tk

class GUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=250, height=250)
        canvas.pack()
        self.bind('<B1-Motion>', lambda x: True)
        self.bind('<Button-1>', lambda x: True)
    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    root = GUI()
    root.mainloop()
```

Your test should workaround the object created from GUI class easily (whether these operations are executed within the constructor or via a different instance method), and to guarantee that the mainloop wouldn't run once you import this file elsewhere, I just added the `if __name__ == "__main__":` block at the end.

Comment: Your are missing between root and mainloop.

Comment: @toyotaSupra Can you elaborate? I don't fully understand your reply.